# Add html content after directive template

Tags: angularjs

Having this HTML :

```
<div messages>
     Some content...
</div>
```

This directive :

```
myAppDirectives.directive("messages", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: '/directives/messages/messages.html',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            //...
        }
    };
});
```

And messages.html :

```
<p>message1</p>
<p>message2</p>
```

The content of my html gets replaced by the directive template but i'd like it to just be appended.

Html becomes this :

```
<div messages>
    <p>message1</p>
    <p>message2</p>
</div>
```

But I'd like this :

```
<div messages>
    <p>message1</p>
    <p>message2</p>
    Some content...
</div>
```

Is this possible without using ng-include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a perfect situation to use [ngTransclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude).
Try:

```
myAppDirectives.directive("messages", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: '/directives/messages/messages.html',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            //...
        }
    };
});
```

messages.html:

```
<p>message1</p>
<p>message2</p>
<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want this behaviour, use transclusion:

```
myAppDirectives.directive("messages", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: '/directives/messages/messages.html',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            //...
        }
    };
});
```

And the template becomes:

```
<p>message1</p>
<p>message2</p>
<span ng-transclude></span>
```

The original content of the `<div messages>` element will be wrapped in the `<span ng-transclude>`, but this should not harm.

Comment: Do you mean by "If you really want this behaviour" that I'm not supposed to want this behaviour?

Comment: Something seems odd about it, but cannot quite express it, so it may be just a personal taste. So feel free to ignore it.